how to show news in next page with php and PDO
I have a problem and want to show my news in more than 1 page with next button
and heres my code : 
<?php

            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, userName, userProfession, userPic, postDate FROM tbl_users ORDER BY userID DESC');
            $stmt->execute();
            $foundData = false;
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                $foundData = true;
                while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    extract($row);
            ?>


                <ul class="col-md-12 blog-posts post-list">
                    <li class="blog-post clearfix">
                        <div class="post-media">
                            <a href="">
                                <img src="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Construction HTML Template"/>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- .post-media end -->
                        <div class="icon-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-body">
                            <div class="post-date">

                                echo '<p>'. mds_date("Y/m/d", strtotime($row['postDate']), 0 ).'</p>'; ?>
                            </div>
                            <a href="">
                                <h3><?php echo $userName."&nbsp;"; ?></h3>
                            </a>

                            <p>
                               <?php echo $userProfession."&nbsp;"; ?>

                            </p>


                        </div><!-- .post-body end -->
                    </li><!-- .blog-post end -->
                                <?php
    }
}
else
{
    if(isset($foundData) && !$foundData){
echo " no data found ." ;
    }
}

?>
</ul>


where you display news and make that div as fixed one it will displayed in all pages

News feed shows only with pageination... First you try with it ...  http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/how-to-create-pagination-with-php-pdo.html @reza

Checkout the MYSQL LIMIT which will do the trick for you and maybe COUNT too

If i was you I would do it with ajax, because ajax can make everything look better and you can do it without refreshing your page check the documentation
https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
But you can limit your query with
   LIMIT $startpage, $per_page;

Hope this helps
